# What is that rest of the background area when you make html body size much smaller than viewport area?

Tags: html, css, viewport

I made an animation using html body. Body background and background size property is being used here. Body background size is much smaller than browser viewport area. But when the body shrinks with a set background color the rest of the viewport area background appear white. I don't know what is that area called and how to style it. My webpage has a dark theme by default but for first 200ms there is a white background. I need to make that black. How can I change the style? What is that rest of the area when body size is 0px?

CSS

```
    body 
    {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, white, #98AEC4, white, #98AEC4, white, white) fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top center; 
        background-size: 85% 2%; 
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 615px) and (orientation: portrait)
    {
    body 
    {
        background-size: 85% 2%;
        animation: mooveme 0.4s;
    }
    }
    @keyframes mooveme
    {
        from
        {
            background-size: 85% 2%;
        }
        to
        {
            background-size: 45% 2%;
        }
    }
```

I have checked forced dark mode on chrome under (chrome://flags/) and it did what I want. How it's forcing the rest of the background color?
Check this page on Android smartphone
https://elomymelo.com/nillkin%20cp+%20pro%20tempered%20glass%20review.html
First 200ms is the animation and the animation is the body size. Rest of the area is white for that 200ms short period of time. I think sudden change to a white color can compromise user experience. I need to change that to a black background.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add this style and change black to your desired color...

```
html { background: black!important; }
```

Comment: It changed the background to black but now the animation in the body is gone. Why the animation is not working now ...?

Comment: Use this...

`html { background-color: black; }`

Comment: Please share the reproducible animation code...

Comment: Forcing google chrome to dark mode for web contents under (chrome://flags/) fixes this problem. What's going on? Do you know what is that part called like the rest of the viewport area when body size is too small?

Comment: I have added (edited) the reproducible code check. Setting background-color to html tag is not working. I tried to set the animation in html tag but then setting body background to black not working. One works but the other one doesn't work.